# Как настроить веб-сервер через ADSL-модем?

Tags: adsl, роутер, localhost

Есть ADSL-подключение, динамический ip. К модему подключен комп, на котором есть веб-сервер. Если извне запросить по айпишнику, открывается страница настройки модема (запароленна). Как сделать, чтобы при обращению к тому Ip-адресу открывался мой локалхост?

Модем Zyxel prestige 600 series

Answer (score 1):

Можно перевести модем в режим моста, а авторизацию поднять на компьютере.

**UPD:** 
Забыл упомянуть пару ещё более простых вариантов:

1. Проброс порта (port forwarding)
2. DMZ (публикация хоста)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого сделай следующие действия:

1. Установи статический IP у себя в свойствах сетевого подключения.
2. Открой страницу модема (которая запоролена) - введи пароль, далее (в меню) Network-NAT-port forwarding-add.
3. Введи любое название, ниже внешний и внутренний порт 80, и свой ip локальный (который ты прописал в 1 пункте).
4. Применяй все изменения и пробуй заходить по внешнему ip.

Будут вопросы - пиши. Удачи.