# Как настроить доступ к web-серверу в локальной сети?

Tags: nginx, debian, домен, роутер, adsl

Тема "избитая", но не нашёл решение, прошу помощи у грамотных людей. Что есть:

1. Домен: `mydom.com`
2. Статический IP от провайдера услуги интернет по ADSL: `xx.yy.zz.ccc`
3. Роутер D-link DSL-2500u/bru/c под эту услугу
4. Switch 16port 10/100
5. Два компьютера, один под Windows Vista, на втором Debian 8 + `nginx`.

Оба компьютера и роутер включены в свитч. Интернет работает на обоих.

**Что хочу:**
Настроить комп. с debian под работу сайта на своем домене `mydom.com`. Пока только осваиваю тему, навыков нет.

**Что сделал:**
Привязал к домену статический IP. Убедился на стороннем ресурсе, что при вводе домена показывает мой IP (`xx.yy.zz.ccc`) и другие данные. Далее пишу по компьютеру с Debian. Есть простой файл `index.html`, его `nginx` выводит в браузер, при наборе в строке браузера : `http://localhost`

Конфиг:

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name localhost;
...
```

Если правильно понял, то сделав коррекцию в конфиге:

```
listen   мой_ip:80;
server_name www.mydom.com mydom.com;
```

должен получить профит. И набрав в строке браузера `mydom.com`, получить исходный файл, причём рассчитывал получать его и на компе с Vista.
Дальше всё грустно.

```
listen   xx.yy.zz.ccc:80; -- не прошел, nginx не запустился (99: Cannot assign      requested address).
listen   ccc.zz.yy.xx:80; -- запустился, но 'ловит' роутер.
```

Пишет: Сайт DSL Router на mydom.com введите имя и пароль. Ну и входит в его админку. На обоих компах. Сделал проброс 80-го порта в настройках роутера, перебирал еще варианты, ничего не получилось.

Вот такой конфиг:

```
listen  192.168.1.3:80;
server_name www.mydom.com mydom.com;
```

Также ловит настройки роутера в браузер, при вводе mydom.com, но, если набрать `http://192.168.1.3` то возвращает нужный файл `html`, причем на обоих компах.

---

**Вопрос:**   Как правильно сделать настройки, чтобы получить рабочую систему?

---

Похожая тема:
[Как настроить веб-сервер через ADSL-модем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/168701/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-adsl-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Это вполне подходящая настройка, в этой строке не требуется изменений:

   ```
   listen   80;
   ```
2. Да, в директиве `server_name` надо указать все имена сервера:

   ```
   server_name www.mydom.com mydom.com;
   ```
3. Если роутер не умеет отдавать в локальную сеть *указанные* адреса для *указанных* доменов, то на **всех** компьютерах в локальной сети (с которых нужен доступ к сайту) следует добавить в `/etc/hosts` (или в его [аналоги в других операционных системах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts)) такую строку:

   ```
   локальный-ip-адрес-сервера www.mydom.com mydom.com
   ```

   где `локальный-ip-адрес-сервера` — адрес, по которому сервер доступен в локальной сети (`192.168.1.3` и т.п.)
4. Если же роутер умеет так делать, то настроить его на такое преобразование:

   ```
   mydom.com → локальный-ip-адрес-сервера
   www.mydom.com → локальный-ip-адрес-сервера
   ```
5. Для того, чтобы сервер всегда был доступен по одному локальному адресу, надо либо в настройках роутера закрепить связку `локальный-ip-адрес-сервера` с его (сервера) *mac-адресом*, либо в сетевых настройках сервера [указать этот адрес как статический](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-a-static-ip-address-tutorial/).
6. Для того, чтобы сервер был доступен извне, в роутере надо настроить проброс 80-го порта из внешнего мира на `локальный-ip-адрес-сервера`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мало опыта у меня, переспрошу : в конфиге оставить listen   80; server_name www.mydom.com mydom.com;. В файле /etc/hosts у

Comment: у меня есть строчки 127.0.0.1   localhost и 127.0.1.1   debian. Туда нужно добавить 127.0.0.1   www.mydom.com mydom.com и всё, а пункты 3 и 4 ? Просто пункт 4 вроде как я делал ранее...

Comment: добавил пункт про `server_name`

Comment: привёл пример, что такое `локальный-ip-адрес-сервера`

Comment: понял, в файл hosts добавлю одну строчку : 192.168.1.3   www.mydom.com mydom.com  и отпишусь, спасибо.

Comment: обратите внимание: `/etc/hosts` надо дополнить на **всех** компьютерах локальной сети.

Comment: да, спасибо. Компьютер на debian уже заработал. По Вашей рекомендации

Comment: буду искать hosts на висте, thanks.

Comment: я специально ссылку привёл — под словами «аналоги в других операционных системах».

Comment: Получилось, большое спасибо.