# доступ к https сайту на Apache из локальной сети

Tags: debian, apache2, https, ssl

Коллеги, нужна ваша помощь.
С Apache на Debian работаю достаточно давно и проблем с настройкой незащищенных виртуальных хостов никогда не возникало. Понадобилось настроить https-сайт. Самоподписанный сертификат сгенерировал, apache настроил, сайт включил, порты на маршрутизаторе пробросил. Сайт заработал. По локальному ip все работает, извне по доменному имени работает, но если обращаться по доменному имени из локальной сети, то нет вообще никакого ответа.
Ответа в интернете не нашел, нужна ваша помощь.

Из локальной сети, но с другой машины:

```
$ wget -S --spider https://yyy.ru  
Включен режим робота. Проверка существования удалённого файла.  
--2015-07-13 15:15:04--  https://yyy.ru/  
Распознаётся yyy.ru (yyy.ru)… 11.11.11.11  
Подключение к yyy.ru (yyy.ru)|11.11.11.11|:443... соединение установлено
```

Извне:

```
$ wget -S --spider https://yyy.ru  
Включен режим робота. Проверка существования удалённого файла.  
--2015-07-13 15:22:11--  https://yyy.ru/  
Распознаётся yyy.ru (yyy.ru)… 11.11.11.11  
Подключение к yyy.ru (yyy.ru)|11.11.11.11|:443... соединение установлено.  
ОШИБКА: Нет доверия сертификату для «yyy.ru».  
ОШИБКА: Сертификат «yyy.ru» неизвестно кем выпущен.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего, вам надо настроить (для локальной сети) разрешение внешнего имени сервера во внутренний *ip-адрес* (или внутреннее имя).

посмотрите на пункты 3 и 4 [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431598/178576).

Comment: Без ssl все работает. т.е. если входить на обычный сайт из локальной сети по его доменному имени, то он отвечает.
Доменное имя у меня зарегистрированное. DNS настроен.

Comment: @servok, приложите в вопрос, пожалуйста, вывод команды (выполненной из локальной сети, но не с сервера) `$ wget -S --spider https://внешнее.имя.сервера`. там будут заголовки и все перенаправления. ну, или сами попробуйте разобраться: возможно, там нежелательный редирект происходит на внутреннее имя или ещё что-нибудь неправильное.

Comment: Вывод приложил. Соединение есть, но дальше ничего пока таймаут не пройдет. Т.е. апач ответил.

Comment: @servok, как я предполагал, и как и предложил в ответе — настройте правильный резолвинг. чтобы в локальной сети имя `yyy.ru` резолвилось не во внешний ip-адрес `11.11.11.11`, а во внутренний.

Comment: Хорошо, так и сделаю, уверен, что будет работать.
Но почему так? Это какая-то особенность ssl?

Comment: сложно дать точный ответ без знания правил маршрутизации и резолвинга имён в вашей сети, а также прочих настроек маршрутизатора. предполагаю, что не совсем правильно настроен тот самый «проброс портов». но для локальной сети решение с правильным резолвингом, с моей точки зрения, наиболее верное.

Comment: кстати, а на какой операционной системе выполнялись команды `wget ...`, вывод которых вы приложили? очень незнакомо они выглядят…

Comment: Самый последний debian.  
Сейчас попытался включить незащищенный сайт и зайти на него так же  - не получилось. Видимо asus что-то сменили в прошивке своего маршрутизатора. А раньше раз у меня все нормально работало он резолвил имена во внутренние ip самостоятельно.
Спасибо. Теперь знаю что дальше делать.

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).