# Открыть доступ к серверу в локальной сети, по доменному имени

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Поднят сервер apache(+php +mysql) на ubuntu. В настройках apache я настроил доменное имя home.loc.

На localhost по доменному имени переходит на сайт отлично.

Что надо сделать, чтобы все машины из локальной сети (подключены к одному роутеру) попадали на мой локальный сайт при вводе адреса `http://home.loc`?

Comment: а почему не взять "глобальное" имя? почему вы использовать "некорректный" домен первого уровня?

Answer (score 2):

частичная копия [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431598/178576) на близкий по смыслу вопрос:

1. если роутер не умеет отдавать в локальную сеть *указанные* адреса для *указанных* доменов, то на **всех** компьютерах в локальной сети (с которых нужен доступ к сайту) следует добавить в `/etc/hosts` (или в его [аналоги в других операционных системах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts)) такую строку:

   ```
   локальный-ip-адрес-сервера home.loc
   ```

   где `локальный-ip-адрес-сервера` — адрес, по которому сервер доступен в локаьной сети (`192.168.1.3` и т.п.)
2. если же роутер умеет так делать, то настроить его на такое преобразование:

   ```
   home.loc → локальный-ip-адрес-сервера
   ```
3. для того чтобы сервер всегда был доступен по одному локальному адресу, надо либо в настройках роутера закрепить связку `локальный-ip-адрес-сервера` с его (сервера) *mac-адресом*, либо в сетевых настройках сервера [указать этот адрес как статический](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-a-static-ip-address-tutorial/).