# Сайт на apache 2 при доступе по ip через https предупреждает о небезопасном соединении

Tags: linux, apache, http, ssl, apache2

**Дано:**

[debian](/questions/tagged/debian), [apache2](/questions/tagged/apache2) на [vps](/questions/tagged/vps), [ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl)-сертификат и домен.

Сертификат вот так подключен в настройках `apache`:

файл `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName mydomain.ru
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.ru

    # Other directives here
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/domain_name.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/private.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/chain.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName mydomain.ru
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.ru

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Сам домен ещё не до конца, видимо, прописался на [dns](/questions/tagged/dns) серверах и я пробую к сайту через `IP` ходить.

**Проблема:**

В итоге я могу по адресам `http://x.x.x.x` и `https://x.x.x.x` попасть на сайт, но в случае `https` браузер жутко ругается на небезопасность соединения. При этом в информации о сертификате браузер говорит что всё ОК и сертификат этот связан с моим доменом.

**Вопрос:**

Так и должно быть и проблема исчезнет когда я буду на сайт ходить по имени домена вместо `IP`? Можно ли это починить чтобы я мог ходить по `IP`-адресу без ругани на безопасность?

Comment: Пропишите домен в файл hosts и проверьте :)

Comment: Сертификат то на домен же выдан, не? Логично, что по ip ругаться будет)

Comment: @andreymal, а можно подробнее? Где файл искать и какой синтаксис прописывания? =)

Comment: @Suvitruf, т.е. это норм и так и должно быть? Или я сертификат неправильно использую? Или неправильно его получил? Или ещё что-то? И можно ли это исправить? =)

Comment: По IP ходить нельзя, потому что сертификат выдан на домен.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, т.е. чтобы по IP ходить по `https` мне нужен ещё один сертификат, который надо получать на конкретный `IP`? И отдельно его в `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` прописывать в отдельном блоке `VirtualHost`?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts

Comment: Мне кажется, на конкретные ip вообще не выдают, но могу ошибаться.

Comment: @andreymal, ага, файл, вроде, нашёл) Прописать там вот так надо, да? `192.168.0.1 www.mydomain.ru mydomain.ru`?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, ну вот( Ацтой(

Comment: @andreymal, в итоге ничего в хосты прописывать не пришлось - оно само заработало)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ответ частично основан на [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119269/4827341).

---

сертификат, соответствующий [стандарту x.509](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_X.509), удостоверят «имя субъекта» (subject). наиболее интересно нам «общепринятое имя» (common name), являющееся частью «имени субъекта».

как правило, оно содержит [fqdn](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FQDN). пример для сертификата, которым подтверждается аутентичность http-сервера, доступного по доменному имени `ya.ru`:

```
$ : | openssl s_client -connect ya.ru:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -subject -nameopt RFC2253
subject=CN=ya.ru,ST=Russian Federation,L=Moscow,OU=ITO,O=Yandex LLC,C=RU
```

`CN=ya.ru` — вот это и есть подтверждаемое сертификатом «общепринятое имя» (common name, сокращённо cn) — `ya.ru`.

с точки зерния стандарта «общепринятое имя», в общем, произвольно. и в применении к сертификатам, подтверждающим аутентичность http-сервера может, теоретически, содержать не доменное имя, а, например, ip-адрес: ведь он ничем не «хуже», чем любая другая *произвольная* строка символов. но на практике такое не встречается (хотя на сайте у какого-то из регистраторов я даже встечал упоминание возможности подтвердить сертификатом ip-адрес).

стоит упомянуть, что нынче одним сертификатом может подтверждаться целый набор доменных имён. пример с тем же сертификатом:

```
$ : | openssl s_client -connect ya.ru:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep DNS
                DNS:ya.ru, DNS:www.ya.ru, DNS:m.ya.ru
```

---

выданный же вам сертификат с вероятностью, равной единице, удоствоверяет именно доменное имя.

убедитесь сами:

```
$ cat файл.с.сертификатом | openssl x509 -noout -subject -nameopt RFC2253
```

поэтому вполне естественным является предупреждение от вашего http-клиента о небезопасности соединения — ведь строка `какое-то.доменное.имя` (которую он «видит» внутри сертификата) абсолютно не совпадает со строкой `какой-то.ip-адрес` (которую вы ввели в адресной строке клиента).

---

по поводу того, как же проверить сертификат (средствами http-клиента), если доменное имя пока не резолвится в нужный ip-адрес, посмотрите, например, [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611181/178576).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь, вроде, всё понятно) И домен заработал уже, ничего больше делать не пришлось)